# Generating all possible combinations of a zeros and b ones

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, python-itertools

Is there an efficient way to generate a list (or an array) of all possible combinations of say 2 ones and 8 zeros? E.g.

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,],
 ...]
```

This works, but there could be a better way?

```
import numpy as np
result = []
for subset in itertools.combinations(range(10), 2):
    subset = list(subset)
    c = np.zeros(10)
    c[subset] = 1
    result.append(c)
```

Would love to have some ideas on how to optimize this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not much different but doing bulk operations on Numpy arrays is bound to have much less overhead:

```
import itertools
import numpy

which = numpy.array(list(itertools.combinations(range(10), 2)))
grid = numpy.zeros((len(which), 10), dtype="int8")

# Magic
grid[numpy.arange(len(which))[None].T, which] = 1

grid
#>>> array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#>>>        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#>>>        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#>>>        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#>>>        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#>>> ...
```

The bulk of the time is then spent doing `numpy.array(list(itertools.combinations(range(10), 2)))`. I tried using `numpy.fromiter` but I didn't get any speed improvements. Since half the time is literally generating the tuples, the only real way to improve further is to generate the combinations in something like C or Cython.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work well. For combinations of 5 1's and 55 0's it gives me the following benchmark: Time (Original solution):  13.2389998436
Time (np.arange):  1.6970000267

Comment: Nice use of fancy indexing! FWIW `np.fromiter(combinations(range(55), 5), np.dtype("i4, i4, i4, i4, i4"), 3478761).view("i4").reshape(-1, 5)` is about 1.7x faster than building a list first, although the advantage doesn't hold for smaller sizes.

Comment: @Jaime Thanks for timing, but I cannot reproduce any speed improvements on Python 2.7 or 3.4. Maybe there was a change in a recent version of Numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using [`numpy.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.8.1/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

```
>>> [np.bincount(xs, minlength=10) for xs in itertools.combinations(range(10), 2)]
[array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64),
 ...]
```

Comment: Love the solution in one line, but this does not seem to be as fast as the above solution. For 5 1's in 50 positions, this solution takes 6.3s compared with the 1.7s of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't we be using permutations for this? Eg,

```
from itertools import permutations as perm
a, b = 6, 2
print '\n'.join(sorted([''.join(s) for s in set(t for t in perm(a*'0' + b*'1'))]))
```

Comment: The whole point was how the original was too inefficient. Using permutations and sorting gives drastically worse timing characteristics. The number of permutations is `O(a!)`, whereas the number of combinations is `O(a! / (b!(a-b)!))`, and `b!(a-b)!` can get very, very large.

Comment: Ok, @Veedrac, that makes sense. :embarrassed: